# Remove vertical spacing from flex-wrap:wrap property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/624MauNg8Xvbjbwt?open=lib%2Fscript.js) here. How to remove the vertical spacing while using `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-content: flex-start;` to `#main`

Comment: remove height poperty css from #main css block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `align-content: flex-start;` on `#main`

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```